# Auto verify email address for autocreated users

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a Meteor project where users need to confirm their email address before they can login.

When the Meteor.user collection is empty I create a default admin user:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

  if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0 ) {

      Accounts.createUser({
          username: 'admin',
          email: 'me@domain.com',
          password: 'admin',
          profile: {
              role: 'admin'
          }
      });

  }

});
```

Even though the user has been created automatically, the user still needs to verify its email address.

How can I automatically set verified to true for this user?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it by using:

```
        Meteor.users.update(user._id, { $set:
          {
            "emails.0.verified": true
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update that user document to set `emails[0].verified` to `true`. That account will be verified but the accounts package will still send out an email asking the user to verify their email address.

Comment: Would be nice if there was a flag on createUser that indicated whether the email should be sent and/or auto verified the email.  As a workaround, you could create the user with an email address that goes to trash and then correct the email when you set verified to true.

Answer (score -2):

Dude, you can  add something like this which searches for the username and assigns value according to the db schema you follow for verification  `(Meteor.users.find({username: 'admin'}).fetch(), ['set your verified to true']);`

Something similar is used to assign admin property to user in Allaning:Roles. Check that out for better understanding.

Comment: To the down voter: I'd like to know where my understanding of the question or my answer went wrong or off topic.